# Automatically creating map for each column of attribute table in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have an atribute table with yearly data for 10 regions, is there a way how to automatically create a set of maps (one for each year) with fixed scale?

I tried to search the web but perhaps I didnt ask the correct question

Picture - how I would like the result to look like
[image: result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goals like this can be achieved using Time Manager but your data would have to look different. Here's a sketch of the attribute table:

```
name,timestamp,value
region1,2009-01-01,100
region2,2009-01-01,120
region1,2010-01-01,90
region2,2010-01-01,121
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was experimenting with time manager, but I had the data in different structure, I read the manual, but did not understand it correctly. So that was the problem. Now it is working.